# How to prove this result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let **{$\Delta_1,\Delta_2,\Delta_3\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\Delta_n$}** be the set of all determinants of order 3 that can be made with the distinct real numbers from set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Then prove that -

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta_i=0$$

Comment: What size are the matrices from which the determinants are calculated? If we use 1 by 1 matrices, the claim is not true.

Comment: Order 3x3. I'll include that in the question details.

Comment: Hint: If one changes two rows in determinant $\Delta$, then it becomes $-\Delta$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel I agree with your answer. I read it after I sent my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about $3\times 3$ matrices.
Take one matrix $A$. You have $6$ possibls permutation on the rows. $3$ even and three odds. Hance you have 3 matrices with determinants $\lambda$ and 3 matrices with determinants $-\lambda$. Take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

We have $n=9!$ determinants: the number of permutations of $9$ components of a $3\times 3$ matrix and let $P$ the set of these determinants. Let  $\Delta$ a given determinant and $\Delta'$ the determinant obtained from $\Delta$ by interchanging its second and third row then we have $\Delta'=-\Delta$. Notice that we can create a partition of $\frac{9!}2$ sets $P_\Delta=\{\Delta,\Delta'\}$ of $P$ and then

$$P=\cup P_\Delta$$
so we see easily that
$$\sum_{\Delta\in P}\Delta=\sum_{\Delta\in P_\Delta}\Delta=0$$